# How to fire ngOnInit on page in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i'm using ionic 5 and angular 9. And using angular Router to move between pages. But this leads me to a problem, in ionic the ngOnInit is not called again. I know that there is a NavController in ionic and the lifecycle events tha it throws... But i need to know if there is a way to use angular Router and have the ngOnInit be called again.

some code to ilustrate...

page 1:

```
goToPerson(person){
this.router.navigateByUrl("/personProfile", {state:person, replaceUrl:true});
}
```

page 2:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.person = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state as Person;

if(this.person.photo != null){
  this.photoPerfil = environment.img_url + this.person.photo.fileName;
}else{
  this.photoPerfil = "../../../assets/images/person.png";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your own Route Reuse Strategy and set shouldReuseRoute to false https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy

Answer (score 0):

i use ionViewWillEnter() instead becouse onInit fire just one time

ngOnInit() Initialize the directive or component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive or component's input properties.
Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().